# 3rd Party Extension Position

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have installed a custom extension that I have purchased from magento extensions. The module displays above the add to cart button on the product page, inside the column on the right hand side. I would like to move the new extension underneath the image and cart options, out of the right hand side. I am a beginner magento developer, I can not figure out how to move this extensions position on the page. I have created custom blocks before and positioned those in different places but I cant seem to find how the extension asks to be positioned.

I am using magento 1.9

Please can somebody point me in the right direction for which file will hold the call for the page position

== == == == UPDATE == == == ==

Ok within app/code/local/BS/Carpet/etc/config.xml I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

1.0.5
        
    
    
        
            
                standard
                
                    BS_Carpet
                    carpet

```
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <BS_Carpet>
                <files>
                    <default>BS_Carpet.csv</default>
                </files>
            </BS_Carpet>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <carpetpricetemplate>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>carpet/observer</class>
                    <method>changeTemplate</method>
                </carpetpricetemplate>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <observers>
                <carpetcustomoptions>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>carpet/observer</class>
                    <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
                </carpetcustomoptions>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>

        <sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <observers>
                <carpetsetprice>
                    <class>carpet/observer</class>
                    <method>quoteItemSetProduct</method>
                </carpetsetprice>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_item_set_product>
    </events>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <carpet>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>BS_Carpet</module>
                <frontName>carpet</frontName>
            </args>
        </carpet>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>     
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <BS_Carpet>
                        <title>Carpet Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </BS_Carpet>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <carpet>
                <file>carpet.xml</file>
            </carpet>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>   
<global>
    <models>
        <carpet>
            <class>BS_Carpet_Model</class>  
            <resourceModel>carpet_mysql4</resourceModel>             
        </carpet>  
        <carpet_mysql4>
            <class>BS_Carpet_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </carpet_mysql4>   
    </models>
    <resources>
        <carpet_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>BS_Carpet</module>
                <class>BS_Carpet_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </carpet_setup>
        <carpet_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </carpet_write>
        <carpet_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </carpet_read>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <carpet>
            <class>BS_Carpet_Block</class>
        </carpet>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <carpet>
            <class>BS_Carpet_Helper</class>
        </carpet>
    </helpers>
</global>
    <default>
    <bs_carpet>
        <general><active>1</active></general>
        <general><width>Width</width></general> 
        <general><length>Length</length></general>                      
    </bs_carpet>
</default>
```

== == == == UPDATE 2 == == == ==

```
<?php
```

class BS_Carpet_Model_Observer {

```
/**

 * Add additional options to order item product options (this is missing in the core)

 *

 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer

 */

public function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

{

    $quoteItem = $observer->getItem();

    if ($additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {

        $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();

        $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();

        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());

        $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);

    }

}



public function changeTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

{

    $_block = $observer->getBlock();

    /*get Block type*/

    $_type = $_block->getType();

    $template = $_block->getTemplate();



    //print_r($_type);

    $currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');

    if($currentProduct){

        if($_type == 'page/html_head'){



            if($currentProduct->getId() && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('bs_carpet/general/active')){

                $isCarpet = $currentProduct->getIsCarpetProduct();

                if($isCarpet){

                    $_block->addItem('skin_css','css/carpet/style.css');

                }



            }

        }









        if($_type == 'catalog/product_view' && strpos($template,'options/wrapper.')){

            if($currentProduct->getId() && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('bs_carpet/general/active')){

                $isCarpet = $currentProduct->getIsCarpetProduct();

                if($isCarpet){



                    $_child = clone $_block;

                    $_child->setType('catalog/product_view');

                    $_child->setTemplate('carpet/calc.phtml');



                    $_block->append($_child);

                }



            }

        }



        if($_type == 'catalog/product_view' && strpos($template,'wrapper/bottom')){

            if($currentProduct->getId() && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('bs_carpet/general/active')){

                $isCarpet = $currentProduct->getIsCarpetProduct();

                if($isCarpet){



                    $_child = clone $_block;

                    $_child->setType('catalog/product_view');

                    $_child->setTemplate('carpet/init.phtml');



                    $_block->append($_child);



                }



            }

        }





    }







}





public function quoteItemSetProduct($observer) {



    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

    if (!$quoteItem || !$quoteItem->getProductId() || !$quoteItem->getQuote() || $quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) return $this;



    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();



    $productId = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getId();

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);



    $widthTitle = strtolower(Mage::getStoreConfig('bs_carpet/general/width'));

    if($widthTitle == '') {$widthTitle = 'width';}

    $lengthTitle = strtolower(Mage::getStoreConfig('bs_carpet/general/length'));

    if($lengthTitle == '') {$lengthTitle = 'length';}





    $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();

    $basePrice = $finalPrice;



    $multi = 1;

    $width = 0;

    $length = 0;

    $optionPrice = 0;





    if($_product->getIsCarpetProduct()==1){

        // prepare post data

        $post = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')->getValue();

        if ($post) $post = unserialize ($post); else $post = array();

        if (isset($post['options'])) $options = $post['options']; else $options = false;







        if ($options) {



            $optionsWeight = 0;

            foreach ($options as $optionId => $option) {





                $productOption = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($optionId);



                $_option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);

                //Mage::log($_option->getTitle());

                $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_'.$_option->getId());

                $value = $confItemOption->getValue();

                //$optionValueModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($value);



                $group = $_option->groupFactory($_option->getType())

                    ->setOption($_option)

                    ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);



                if(strtolower($_option->getTitle())==$lengthTitle){



                    if($_option->getType() == 'drop_down'){

                        $length = (float)$group->getFormattedOptionValue($confItemOption->getValue());

                    }else {

                        $length = (float)$confItemOption->getValue();

                    }



                }else if(strtolower($_option->getTitle())==$widthTitle){



                    if($_option->getType() == 'drop_down'){

                        $width = (float)$group->getFormattedOptionValue($confItemOption->getValue());

                    }else {

                        $width = (float)$confItemOption->getValue();

                    }

                }



                $optionPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);







            }



            $dimenion = $width * $length;



            $tierPrice = $this->getTierPrice($dimenion, $product);



            if(is_array($tierPrice)){

                $tierPrice = $finalPrice;

            }



            if($tierPrice > $finalPrice){

                $tierPrice = $finalPrice;

            }



            $totalPrice = $dimenion * ($tierPrice + $optionPrice);



            $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($totalPrice);

            $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($totalPrice);





        }

    }





    return $this;

}



public function getTierPrice($qty = null, $product)

{

    $allGroups = Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL;

    $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');



    if (is_null($prices)) {

        $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');

        if ($attribute) {

            $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);

            $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');

        }

    }



    if (is_null($prices) || !is_array($prices)) {

        if (!is_null($qty)) {

            return $product->getPrice();

        }

        return array(array(

            'price'         => $product->getPrice(),

            'website_price' => $product->getPrice(),

            'price_qty'     => 1,

            'cust_group'    => $allGroups,

        ));

    }



    $custGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);

    if ($qty) {

        $prevQty = 1;

        $prevPrice = $product->getPrice();

        $prevGroup = $allGroups;



        foreach ($prices as $price) {

            if ($price['cust_group']!=$custGroup && $price['cust_group']!=$allGroups) {

                // tier not for current customer group nor is for all groups

                continue;

            }

            if ($qty < $price['price_qty']) {

                // tier is higher than product qty

                continue;

            }

            if ($price['price_qty'] < $prevQty) {

                // higher tier qty already found

                continue;

            }

            if ($price['price_qty'] == $prevQty && $prevGroup != $allGroups && $price['cust_group'] == $allGroups) {

                // found tier qty is same as current tier qty but current tier group is ALL_GROUPS

                continue;

            }

            if ($price['website_price'] < $prevPrice) {

                $prevPrice  = $price['website_price'];

                $prevQty    = $price['price_qty'];

                $prevGroup  = $price['cust_group'];

            }

        }

        return $prevPrice;

    } else {

        $qtyCache = array();

        foreach ($prices as $i => $price) {

            if ($price['cust_group'] != $custGroup && $price['cust_group'] != $allGroups) {

                unset($prices[$i]);

            } else if (isset($qtyCache[$price['price_qty']])) {

                $j = $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']];

                if ($prices[$j]['website_price'] > $price['website_price']) {

                    unset($prices[$j]);

                    $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $i;

                } else {

                    unset($prices[$i]);

                }

            } else {

                $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $i;

            }

        }

    }



    return ($prices) ? $prices : array();

}



protected function _getCustomerGroupId($product)

{

    if ($product->getCustomerGroupId()) {

        return $product->getCustomerGroupId();

    }

    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Usualy, well built modules can add it's blocks in next way:

Module have custom layout (xml) file, which mentioned in module/etc/config.xml  and can look like

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <neklo_giftcard>
            <file>neklo/giftcard.xml</file>
        </neklo_giftcard>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

look for it in  section of config.

In the layout file of module you can have construction like:

```
<reference name="PARENT_BLOCK_NAME">
     <block type="your_module_name/custom_module_block" name="CUSTOM_BLOCK_NAME" template="custom_module_template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Which means that module is adding it's block into Default Magento parent block.

In your case it can look like

```
<reference name=" name="product.info.addtocart">
```

or

```
<reference name="addtocart">
```

and you have to change it to

```
<reference name="product.info">
```

and after that, you'll need to place your block in catalog/product/view.phtml file, by calling

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('CUSTOM_BLOCK_NAME') ?>
```

in the place you will choose.

But other ways of adding custom blocks are also possible and they can be very different. So if you'll provide at least config.xml of your module - we can try to find exact answer

==== UPDATE ====

Ok, so you will need to open file

app/code/local/BS/Carpet/Model/Observer.php

and find

```
public function changeTemplate()
```

Inside that fuction you will see one or several PHTML files mentioned, which replace default magento templates.
But changing this custom templates you should be able to move your block in correct position. 
But, be attentive - if these custom blocks contain form elements, so they probably can not be moved out of Add To Cart form.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, I will have a look into your points. If I still cant find it I will start adding information from the files for some more help. Thank you very much

Comment: I have updated the original post and added the info from the config.xml, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Answer is also updated

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, so if I understand correctly, because the extension is part of the form (uses information of the product to calculate the floor size and the amount needed) then I am unable to move the position out of the area where the product information is held?

Comment: Probably so. The minimum changes you can made is to move block after Add To Cart button, but before </form> element. But visually it can be placed far away from product information and it's based on your theme and design.

Comment: one last question, which part of the Observer.php file is the command for placing the module?

Comment: see my new answer with more code lines mentions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40815/discussion-between-neklo-com-and-adrian).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the block you are trying to move is generated at

```
if($_type == 'catalog/product_view' && strpos($template,'options/wrapper.')){

            if($currentProduct->getId() && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('bs_carpet/general/active')){

                $isCarpet = $currentProduct->getIsCarpetProduct();

                if($isCarpet){

                    $_child = clone $_block;

                    $_child->setType('catalog/product_view');

                    $_child->setTemplate('carpet/calc.phtml');

                    $_block->append($_child);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this place custom block inside catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml
and if you will replace

```
$_block->append($_child);
```

with

```
$_block->setChild('CUSTOM_BLOCK_NAME', $_child);
```

you should be able to call

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('CUSTOM_BLOCK_NAME') ?>
```

in catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml 
And it's hard to tell if calc.phtml template (custom block) can be moved out of options wrapper.

Comment: that has made the extension appear in the exact same place. When i try the php echo call in the view.phtml it does not appear

Comment: I need to call it in a different file but the place is still within the </form>

Comment: To move this block to view.phtml  you have to change Observer line:  "if($_type == 'catalog/product_view' && strpos($template,'options/wrapper.')){"   TO  "if($_type == 'catalog/product_view' && strpos($template,'catalog/product/view.phtml')){".  But there are no guarantee that custom block will work as it should after all.

Comment: No, unfortunately that has not made it display either.